# app not reading stylesheets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

My app is only reading my application.css.scss stylesheet and I'd like the other stylesheets to read in the application.  Haven't encountered this problem before.  I tried renaming the other stylesheets with the following extensions (.css.scss and .css) and tried different variation of my gems, but nothing seems to work.  Here are my current stylesheets:

```
application.css.scss
static_pages.scss
users.scss
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'pg',           '0.17.1'
gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_security_extension'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
```

end

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'

end
```

Application stylesheet:

```css
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */


@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap"
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like your `application` file is an scss file.
so you'll need to import the files with `@import`.

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "static_pages";
@import "users";
```